# Is this a textbook design pattern, or did I invent something new?

Tags: sql, design-patterns, relational

I'm fresh out of designing a set of tables, in which I came up with an architecture that I was very pleased with!  I've never seen it anywhere else before, so I'd love to know if I've just reinvented the wheel (most probable), or if this is a genuine innovation.

Here's the problem statement: I have `Employees` who can each sign a different contract with the company.  Each employee can perform different Activities, and each activity may have a different pay rate, sometimes a fixed amount for completing one activity, sometimes an hourly rate, and sometimes at a tiered rate.  There may also be a specific customer who likes the employee particularly, so when he works with that specific customer, he gets a higher rate.  And if no rate is defined, he gets the company default rate.

Don't fuss about the details: the main point is that there are a lot of pay rates that can be defined, each in a fairly complicated way.  And the pay rates all have the following in common:

- Service Type
- Pay Scale Type (Enum: Fixed Amount/Hourly Rate/Tiered Rate)
- Fixed Amount (if PayScaleType = FA)
- Hourly Rate (if PayScaleType = HR) - yes, could be merged into one field, but for reasons I won't go into here, I've kept them separate
- Tiers (1->n relationship, with all the tiers and the amount to pay once you have gone over the tier threshold)

These pay rates apply to:

- Default company rate
- Employee rate
- Employee override rate (defined per customer)

If I had to follow the simple brute force approach, I would have to create a `PayRate` and `PayRateTier` clone table for each of the 3 above tables, plus their corresponding Linq classes, plus logic to calculate the rates in 3 separate places, somehow refactoring to reuse the calculation logic.  Ugh.  That's like using copy and paste, just on the database.

So instead, what did I do?  I created a intermediary table, which I called `PayRatePackage`, consisting only of an ID field.  I have only **one** `PayRate` table with a mandatory FK to `PayRatePackage`, and a `PayRateTier` table with a mandatory FK to `PayRate`.  Then, `DefaultCompanyPayRate` has a mandatory FK to `PayRatePackage`, as do `EmployeeRate` and `EmployeeOverrideRate`.

So simple - and it works!

(Pardon me for not attaching diagrams; that would be a lot of effort to go to for a SO question where I've already solved the main problem.  If a lot of people want to see a diagram, please say so in the comments, and I'll throw something together.)

Now, I'm pretty sure that something this simple and effective must be in a formal design pattern somewhere, and I'd love to know what it is.  Or did I just invent something new?  :)

Comment: Why not write this up, with diagrams and place it on your blog?

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty sure this is the [Strategy Pattern](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?StrategyPattern)

"Define a family of algorithms, encapsulate each one, and make them interchangeable. Strategy lets the algorithm vary independently from clients that use it."

Comment: I don't think so.  Strategy Pattern refers to an OO design, not a DB architecture.

Comment: Funny, I've seen the design pattern implemented in non-OO languages. A pattern is typically language agnostic.

Comment: well, that's what you get for using the highly polluted term "design pattern"

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like relational database design to me.  You broke out specific logic into specific entities, and keyed them back to the original tables... Standard normalization...

Comment: Sure it's relational DB design (I retagged the question now) - but is this a standard, textbook use of relational tables? If I'd thought about it less and gone with brute force, I would have made separate PayRate and PayRateTier tables for each of the three contexts in which they apply, each one with a FK to its respective parent table.  The novelty here is the use of the PayRatePackage table to "normalize" data that doesn't actually apply to the same parent objects.  Or is that not much of a novelty?

Comment: It's clever, but I wouldn't say it's something new.